# Downgrade to iTunes with App Store support

Tags: macos, itunes, high-sierra

I was trying to downgrade my iTunes to an earlier version so I can access my App Wishlist and copy it and then upgrade to the latest.

I came across a webpage that suggested navigating to the Applications folder via terminal and deleting the iTunes app via `sudo rm -rf iTunes.app/` however many files didn't get deleted and this left me unable to open iTunes anymore and I can't install an earlier version since the install thinks I have a newer version.

Is there a way to fix my iTunes (at least get the newest version fixed/to work again) instead of maybe reseting macOS?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to re-install via your backup... At lest that would be the first thing I would try...

Comment: You'll have to do it from a backup, as the library is not backwardly-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up downloading the official iTunes installer from Apple and reinstalling it. Since it's the newest version, I didn't get any errors saying that I have a newer version.
Works as before now.

Comment: You can also get the latest official version by checking for system updates from within the Mac App Store. Official installer comes handy when wishing to downgrade to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to attempt force delete of stock macOS apps.

You can downgrade iTunes by downloading and installing the older version by following the instructions on this Apple Support document, [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208079). Here, you can find links to download iTunes **12.6.4** and instructions on installing it.